# передача из edit в другой edit "на лету"

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте! Впервые столкнулся с WinAPI и не получается передать "на лету" текст из одного эдита в другой. При этом нужно, чтобы в конечном итоге текст отображался по правилу "нечетный символ в верхний регистр, четный в нижний регистр".
Вот мой код. То, что в case WM_CHAR не работает.

```
#include <windows.h>


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND,  UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInst,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    TCHAR szClassName[] = L"Мой класс";
    HWND hMainWnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wc.cbWndExtra = NULL;
    wc.cbClsExtra = NULL;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {

        MessageBox(NULL, L"Не получилось зарегистрировать класс!", L"Ошибка", MB_OK);
        return NULL;
    }

    hMainWnd = CreateWindow(
                   szClassName,
                   L"Laba",
                   WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VSCROLL,
                   CW_USEDEFAULT,
                   NULL,
                   CW_USEDEFAULT,
                   NULL,
                   (HWND)NULL,
                   NULL,
                   HINSTANCE(hInst),
                   NULL);
    if (!hMainWnd) {

        MessageBox(NULL, L"Не получилось создать окно!", L"Ошибка", MB_OK);
        return NULL;
    }
    ShowWindow(hMainWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hMainWnd);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;




}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd,  UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    TCHAR buf[256];
    HWND textbox;
    HWND textbox1;
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CREATE:

        textbox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", L"", WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_LEFT,
                                 50, 50, 200, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)hWnd, NULL, NULL);
        ShowWindow(textbox, SW_NORMAL);
        UpdateWindow(textbox);

        textbox1 = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", L"", WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_LEFT,
                                  50, 100, 200, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)hWnd, NULL, NULL);
        ShowWindow(textbox1, SW_NORMAL);
        UpdateWindow(textbox1);

        break;

    case WM_CHAR:
        GetWindowText(textbox, buf, sizeof(buf) / sizeof(buf[0]));
        SendMessage(textbox1, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)buf);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(NULL);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: То, что в WM_CHAR, вообще не выполняется - до него управление не доходит. Вам нужно добраться до обработчика `textbox`